# Сравнить значение из строки

Tags: php, php7

Мне нужно сравнить значения из строки и если они совпадают присваивать единицу значение.

```html
if ($strBin == 1 || $strBin == 0) {
   return 1;
}
if ($strBin == " ") {
    return "\n";
}
echo "Вывод зашифрованного значения:"."</br>".$strBin."</br>"; // Вывод зашифрованной строки
```

У меня выводит то же значение что и было изначально.

Пробовал вот так

```html
$arraySource = str_split($strBin); 
$arrayBinary1 = array_map(function() {

$arrayBinary = array_map(function() {
   return 1."\n";
}, $arraySource);

$strBinary = implode($arrayBinary); // закодированная строка
echo "Содержание файла:"."</br>".$strBinary."</br>";
```

Такой код вывод зашифрованное сообщение, но после каждого символа делает пробел, а мне нужно что бы было вот так:

Исходное сообщение: 0100 1101 0011

Закодированное сообщение единицами: 1111 1111 1111

**В Примере 1 выводит вот так:**

Исходное сообщение: 0100 1101 0011

**В Примере 2 выводит вот так:**

Исходное сообщение: 0100 1101 0011

Закодированное сообщение единицами: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1

Comment: Уберите `."\n"`

Comment: Если убрать \n будет все в одну строчку вот так: 111111. А мне надо 1111 1111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам просто нужно сохранять исходные пробелы:

```
$str = '1001 1100 0100 1101';

$encoded = implode(array_map(fn($ch) => $ch === ' ' ? ' ' : '1', str_split($str)));

echo $encoded; // 1111 1111 1111 1111
```

---

```
$str = '1001 1100 0100 1101';

$encoded = implode(array_map(function($ch) { 
  return $ch === ' ' ? ' ' : random_int(0, 1);
}, str_split($str)));

echo $encoded;
```

[3v4l](https://3v4l.org/ILMNI)

Comment: Можно ли в эту функцию добавить возможность рандомного вывода не просто все единицы а вот например 0111 0111 1100?

Comment: Замените `'1'` на что угодно

Comment: Во-первых, ваш скрипт не работает) Пишет "syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW), expecting ',' or ')". Во-вторых мне не нужно все изменить на конкретное число а нужно random_int добавить

Comment: Прекрасно работает в php>=7.4, замените '1' на `random_int(0, 1)` и будет то, что нужно.

Comment: Вот это ваше во вторых нужно добавить в вопрос

Comment: Простите, потом уже придумал это. Спасибо, ваш ответ помог!

Answer (score 1):

```
$a = '0100 1101 0011';
echo str_replace([0,1],1,$a); //1111 1111 1111
```

Comment: А сюда как-то можно впихнуть функцию random_int что бы рандомно брать 1 или 0 для каждого бита?

Comment: рандомно брать 1 или 0 для каждого бита - эта фраза не понятна. $a содержит в себе текст. Если кодировка UTF-8 то каждый символ это 16bit(2 байта) если другая то каждый символ будет 8 bit(1 байт)